# How to restore Window control Button Like Maximize Minimuze and cancel button

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I'm facing a problem in my Windows OS which is running an antivirus program `360 Total Security`. This program changes my windows settings totally. My window control button is not appearing. Also, my browser new tab is not appearing. Can anyone please tell me how to show window control button?

Comment: Did you try to disable your antivirus and your problem is gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Uninstall my Antivirus program. Reboot my system and got all previous setting